# How to exit from coroutine in unity in specific condition?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

i have some problems with coroutines in unity. I want that my player when he gets to the door (when a collision occurs) to enter in the tower after 3 seconds, and if he moves within less than 3 seconds from the door to close the door and not load a new scene. I tried most of things but doesn't work. Can somebody help or give me some hint?

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Door : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private Animator animator;
bool open = false;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        animator.SetBool("opening", true);
        StartCoroutine("LoadLevelTowerAfterDelay");
    }
    else
    {
        animator.SetBool("opening", false);
        StopCoroutine("LoadLevelTowerAfterDelay");
    }
}
IEnumerator LoadLevelTowerAfterDelay()
{

    if (GameManager.sharedInstance != null)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        GameManager.sharedInstance.LoadLevelTower();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnTriggerStay2D` is called **every physics update frame**!

You definitely do **NOT** want to start a new coroutine every physics frame!

What you rather want to do is using `OnTriggerEnter2D` and `OnTriggerExit2D` like e.g.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (!collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) return;
    
    animator.SetBool("opening", true);
    StartCoroutine(LoadLevelTowerAfterDelay());
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (!collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) return;
    
    animator.SetBool("opening", false);
    StopCoroutine(LoadLevelTowerAfterDelay());
}
```

in general this should already work but to be save you could store the started routine as also mentioned here

```
private Coroutine currentRoutine;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (!collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) return;
    
    // This should actually not happen
    if(currentRoutine != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Huh?!", this);
        return;
    }

    animator.SetBool("opening", true);
    currentRoutine = StartCoroutine(LoadLevelTowerAfterDelay());
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (!collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) return;
    
    // This should actually not happen
    if(currentRoutine == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Huh?!", this);
        return;
    }

    animator.SetBool("opening", false);
    StopCoroutine(currentRoutine);
    currentRoutine = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks derHugo, you are definitely right, i tried before with OnTriggerEnter2D but  then i did not have OnTriggerExit2D and like we can see from your answer i must have both triggers for what i want. Thanks once again

Answer (score 3):

Just for Completion

you can exit/finish the coroutine from within with `yield break`

an example would be:

```
public IEnumerator MyCoroutine(){
   DoStuff();
   if(condition){
      yield break; 
   }
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
   DoOtherStuff();
}
```

this way you would preemptively end the coroutine, not wait 4 seconds and don't DoOtherStuff();

Answer (score 0):

One option is: If something happens that makes you want to cancel the operation, set a boolean somewhere and check for it immediately before the `LoadLevelTower()` line in the coroutine.

Another option is to keep a reference to the coroutine (e.g. `Coroutine c = StartCoroutine("LoadLevelTowerAfterDelay");`), then if something happens that makes you want to abort it, use `StopCoroutine(c);`.

I think your larger problem might be in your use of `OnTriggerStay2D` though. To me it looks like you’re calling `StartCoroutine` every frame while a player is within the collider, and `StopCoroutine` every frame while **something other than a player** is within the collider. Probably you instead want to be using `OnTriggerEnter2D` to check for a player entering, and `OnTriggerExit2D` to check for a player exiting?

Comment: Thanks Seven Viking. You are also right, and your answer can help. Thanks once again.